# Add to a dynamic array in D?

Tags: d

I must be missing something obvious now, but I can't figure out how to add elements to a dynamic array in D.

I have tried this, without success:

```
string[] links;
foreach(link; someOtherArray) {
    // Do something with link ...
    links[] = link; // Trying here to add to the links array
}
```

and this:

```
string[] links;
int i = 0;
foreach(link; someOtherArray) {
    // Do something with link ...
    links[i] = link; // Trying here to add to the links array
    i++;
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the concat operator: a ~ b or a ~= b;

```
string[] links;
foreach(link; arr) {
     links ~= link;
}
```

The right side can be an individual element or another array.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that, if possible, you should preallocate the correct length for an array first as this will be *much* faster in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

For this case the following might also work:

```
string[] links;
links ~= someOtherArray;
```